# WETH Transaction does not appear in the web3.eth.get_transaction

Tags: python, web3py

I am trying to understand how can I see the amount of WETH transferred in a transaction. for example on OpenSea. When you go to etherscan you can see the amount. but if you use web3.eth.get_transcation(tx_hash) you will find the value to be 0 ( since its WETH and not ETH).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having trouble with this.
The Phunkbot code is on github (https://github.com/albanow/phunks-nll-twitter-bot/blob/main/bot.py), and this part from the 'input' is interesting:

```
bid = "0x6d728796"
sale = "0xf8529df3"
accepted_bid = "0xbad9f860"
```

Somehow the first 10 characters of the 'input' hex is a sign of what kind of transaction it is? Doesn't seem to be the case for the contract I'm trying to monitor but maybe this code will lead you somewhere.

Comment: This is not an answer really. Try to delete this answer and write it as a comment.

Comment: i can't because i don't have enough reputation, sorry.